# Aggregation to print out posts/reposts

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the main schema for posts and I would like to make such a timeline API which returns all posts by the logged in user, any post belong to one of the followed users & any post that been reposted by one of the followed users

Here I have three schemas

• Users

• Posts

• Reposts

For `users` schema, it has an array field containing all followed users by their `ObjectId (reference)`

Any small hint for that?

Comment: Your `Users` schema will have multiple documents where each document will look like: `{
 userId:"1234",
 posts:[
         {_id:"post_id",
           title: "post title",
           tags:["tag1","tag2","tag3"]
         },
         {...}
 ]
}`

Comment: For posts I created different schema (collection) which have field reference for the user

Comment: That completely nullifies the purpose of MongoDB! If you want to stick with all relations and constraints, then go with relational databases.

Comment: So could you please provide me an example for reposts

Comment: I believe the point here is that you are essentially asking *"which would be best to do"* or either *"show me how to do everything"*. The first point is purely a matter of "opinion" as far as others are concerned, and only your application can decide on what is best for it based on how you actually want to use the data. Aggregation is just "one" usage out of your whole data access pattern. That said, why would you use MongoDB at all if all you are going to do is use the "same relational pattern"? So we really cannot tell you "how to do it", and instead you should be reading and testing.

Comment: Got it, MongoDB is not a relational cause